# Can I have Wireframe view + material preview At the Same Time

Tags: materials, interface, workflow, wireframe

I am currently watching a tutorial where the author goes in the wireframe view,but he is still in the materail preview.He uses a key f3 for wireframe which is by default in blender ,but when i do the same it shifts me to wireframe view but not in the material preview.Below i have attached the pics where the other guys mesh is in the wireframe preview but also in the material preview[image]

Answer (score 2):

In material preview you can show an object's wireframe:

[image]

Or you can show all object's wireframes:

[image]